# Queue array pointers (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, queue

I'm new to C++. And thus also the idea of using pointers.
I have some arrays that I want to queue. I understand that my code does not work as I'm using pointers. However I do not know how I should fix this? 
I need the elements from the queue to be a float* type for later use with BLAS.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;


float* initialize(float* vec, int len){
    for(int i = 0; i < len; ++i){
        vec[i] = 0;     // Initialize
    }
    return vec;
}

void printVector(float* vec, int len){
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
        cout << vec[i] << endl;
    cout << "--" << endl;
}

int main ()
{
    queue<float*> q;
    int len = 3;
    float* k = new float[len];
    k = initialize(k,len);

    for(int t=0;t<len;t++){
        k[t] = 1;   
        printVector(k, len);
        q.push(k);
        k[t] = 0;
    }

    // I would like the one below to give same output as above
    cout << "Should have been the same:" << endl;

    while (!q.empty()){
        printVector(q.front(), len);
        q.pop();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Bonus question does these types of "pointer arrays" have a special name? 
float* k = new float[len];

Comment: You could use `std::vector<float>`. If you have to pass C arrays to BLAS functions you could extract them using `std::vector::data()` (or `&std::vector::operator[0]`). The size (number of elements) (which is probably required as well) is available with `std::vector::size()`.

Comment: `k` is just a pointer to the first element of the new array. It is indistinguishable from a pointer to any other `float`, except in what you can/must do with it.

Comment: Thanks. And yes, I understand that. However, I do not know how to come around this if I want q.front() to be a float*.

Comment: @Christian you probably don't need that. If you used a `std::queue<std::vector<float>>` you could just as easily do `q.front().data()`.

Comment: In general, you can do it the way you tried BUT: you allocate storage only once. To make it working you have to allocate storage in the loop (the one with the `q.push();`). The other loop should `delete[]` the popped pointer resp. (Otherwise you might get memory leaks.) As you did it, all queue entries share the same storage (and hence the side effects). => Assigning a pointer does not copy the pointed contents.

Comment: @Scheff Prefer `data()`, as it is a valid operation even if the vector has no elements (unlike creating a pointer to the first element).

Comment: @MaxLanghof Good catch. I just had a look into [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data): _The pointer is such that range `[data(); data() + size())` is always a valid range, even if the container is empty (`data()` is not dereferenceable in that case)._ and _If `size()` is 0, `data()` may or may not return a null pointer._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The essential message is: Storing a pointer (to an array or what ever) does not copy the contents. It just copies the address of it.

Re-ordering your statements a bit I got OP's sample running (and doing what's probably intended):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;


float* initialize(float* vec, int len){
    for(int i = 0; i < len; ++i){
        vec[i] = 0;     // Initialize
    }
    return vec;
}

void printVector(float* vec, int len){
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
        cout << vec[i] << endl;
    cout << "--" << endl;
}

int main ()
{
    queue<float*> q;
    int len = 3;

    for(int t=0;t<len;t++){
        float* k = new float[len];
        k = initialize(k,len);
        k[t] = 1;   
        printVector(k, len);
        q.push(k);
    }

    // I would like the one below to give same output as above
    cout << "Should have been the same:" << endl;

    while (!q.empty()){
        printVector(q.front(), len);
        delete[] q.front();
        q.pop();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1
0
0
--
0
1
0
--
0
0
1
--
Should have been the same:
1
0
0
--
0
1
0
--
0
0
1
--
```

---

Using `new` in C++ is error prone and can be prevented in many cases. Doing the same with `std::vector<float>`, it could look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void printVector(const float* vec, int len){
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
        cout << vec[i] << endl;
    cout << "--" << endl;
}

int main ()
{
    queue<std::vector<float> > q;
    int len = 3;

    for(int t=0;t<len;t++){
        q.push(std::vector<float>(3, 0.0f));
        q.back()[t] = 1.0f;
        printVector(q.back().data(), q.back().size());
    }

    // I would like the one below to give same output as above
    cout << "Should have been the same:" << endl;

    while (!q.empty()){
        printVector(q.front().data(), q.front().size());
        q.pop();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output is identical.

<kbd>[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c4b77f4bb9eba1bf)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks Scheff! Exactly what I was looking for.